# Why doesn't the Bitcoin Wallet mobile app require the whole blockchain?

Tags: wallet, bitcoin-core, bitcoin-wallet-app

I use the Bitcoin-Core on PC, where it starts by downloading the whole blockchain, before one can use the wallet.
Why doesn't it require to download the blockchain in case of the mobile app?